# Integer CSV Compression Algorithm

Tags: csv, compression

I did surface level research about the existance of an algorithm that compresses comma seperated integers however i did not find anything relevant.

My goal is to compress large amounts of structured comma separated integers whos value ranges are known. Is there a known algorithm to do such a thing? If not where would be a good start to read about some relevant areas of interest which will get me started on developing such algorithm? Ofcourse the algorithm has to be reversable and lossles such that i can uncompress the compressed data to retrieve the csv values.

The data structure is an array of three values, first number's domain is from 0 to 4, second is from 0 to 6, third is from 0 to n where n is not a large number. This structure is repeated to create data which is in a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard compression algorithms such as gzip or bzip2 on structured data does not yield optimum compression efficiency, therefore constructing a case specific algorithm did the trick.

The data structure is shown below with an example.

```
// cell: a data structure, array of three numbers
// digits[0]: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
// digits[1]: { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
// digits[2]: { 0, 1, 2, ..., n } n is not an absurdly large number
// Below it is reused in a multi-dimensional array.
var cells = [
    [ [3, 0, 1], [4, 2, 4], [3, 0, 2], [4, 1, 3] ],
    [ [4, 2, 3], [3, 0, 3], [4, 3, 3], [1, 1, 0] ],
    [ [3, 3, 0], [2, 3, 1], [2, 2, 5], [0, 2, 4] ],
    [ [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0] ]
];
```

I did various tests on this data structure (excluding the white-spaces as string) using standard compression algorithms:

- gz compressed from 171 to 88 bytes
- bzip2 compressed from 171 to 87 bytes
- deflate compressed from 171 to 76 bytes

The algorithm I constructed compressed the data down to 33 bytes works up till n = 192. So on a case specific basis I was able to compress my data with more than double efficiency of standard text compression algorithms.

The way I achieved such compression is by mapping the possible values of all the different combinations which cells can hold to integers. If you want to investigate such a concept it's known as combinatorics in Mathematics. I then converted the base 10 integer into a higher base for string representation.

Since I am aiming for human usability (the compressed code will be typed) I used base 62 which I represented as {[0-9], [a-z], [A-Z]} from 0 to 61 respectively. I buffered the cell length when converted to Base62 to two digits. This allowed for 62*62 (3844) different cell combinations.

Finally, I added a base 62 digit at the beginning of the compressed string which represents the number of columns. When decompressing the y size is used to deduce the x size from the string's length. Thus the data can be correctly decompressed with no loss of data.

The compressed string of the above example looks like this:

```
var uncompressed = compress(cells); // "4n0w1H071c111h160i0B0O1s170308110"
```

I have provided an explanation of my method to solve my problem to help other facing a similar problem. I have not provided my code for obscurity reasons.

**TL;DR**

To compress structured data:

1. Represent discrete object as an integer
2. Encode the base 10 integer to a higher base
3. Repeat for all objects
4. Append number of rows or columns to the compressed string

To decompress structured data:

1. Read the rows or columns and deduce the other from the string length
2. Reverse steps 1 and 2 in compression
3. Repeat for all objects

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some specific structure to your list that you're not divulging and that might drastically help compression, standard lossless compression algorithms such a `gzip` or `bzip2` should handle a string of numbers just fine.

Libraries for such common algorithms should be ubiquitously available for pretty much all languages and platforms.

Comment: I would like to construct a case specific algorithm for csv integers to possibly boost compression. That is why i am avoiding general lossless text compression algorithms.

Comment: @OmarChehab: But the general algorithms will work just fine for this. What is the concrete goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Given the data's known structure I would like to explore methods to construct a case specific algorithm to boost compression efficiency. Surely the general compression algorithms will work, no doubt about that. I will use them if there is no possible way in this given scenario to beat their compression efficiency.